# Error while trying to reverse a char array

Tags: c

I'm trying to get better at C++ (I know a little). I'm working on character arrays. I found an exercise where the objective is to reverse a character array (after I convert it from an integer). I'm getting the following error (using VS2005):

Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'revBuffer' was corrupted.

When I step through the code, I notice the following:

revBuffer = 0x0012fe40 "100899ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ998001"

The relevant code is below.

```
    char buffer[5];
    char revBuffer[5];
    int i;
    int j=5;
    long number = 998001;

    itoa(number, buffer, 10);

    for(i=0; i<strlen(buffer);i++)
    {
        revBuffer[j] = buffer[i];
        j--;
    }
```

Any help would be great. TIA!

Comment: Just trace through your code - look at the values of the indices that'll be used in the first iteration of the for loop.

Comment: Not related to your bug, but you should hoist `strlen(buffer)` out of the `for` loop expression, so that it doesn't get computed needlessly in every loop. `strlen` works by scanning the entire string until it sees the null terminator. I think that leaving `strlen` in the loop would be a form of "premature pessimization" (IMHO).

Comment: @Emile Premature pessimization, haha.

Comment: This is `c` not `c++`, I retagged appropriately. The C++ code would be using `std::string` and `.at()` which would have indicated the `out_of_range` issue.

Comment: @WhirlWind: I did not coin that term. I first saw it in the C++ Coding Standards book by Sutter and Alexandrescu. :-)

Comment: @Emile: I dunno, buffer is 7 whole bytes (once the bugs are fixed). Count 'em. Count 'em 7 times if you like: I for one am happy to wait while you do that. Agreed though that it's a bad habit in general to turn an O(n) op into an O(n^2) op for no reason. @Matthieu, if you're going to insist on proper use of libraries, then "the" C++ code would use `copy_backward`, not `at()`. End of discussion ;-)

Comment: @Steve: He he, true. :-) But... think of what you can otherwise do in those 7 times X nanoseconds!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are overindexing revBuffer.  It is size 5, which means you can index it from 0 to 4, but the first index you use in it in your loop is 5.

Comment: Damn. That was a dumb mistake on my part. All the answers and suggestions were a big help. This site rocks! Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

The number you are converting has six digits - the buffer you are using is only big enough to hold 4 plus a null terminator. Make the buffer bigger.

Answer (score 2):

While your excercise is helpful you should keep in mind that there also is:

```
std::reverse(buffer, buffer + 5);
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what others have said, It doesn't appear that a null terminator will be placed in the last character of revBuffer even after you fix all your indexing issues. You will need to be sure to do

```
revBuffer[strlen(buffer)] = '\0';
```

This is also frought with problems because it assumes that buffer is properly terminated :)

Answer (score 0):

For a start, you're trying to use a buffer that's 5 characters long to store a 6 digit number.